# Hide Header of Bottom tab bar inside nested stack screen in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation, stack-navigator, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I have a Bottom tab bar navigator with three Tabs:
HomeStack
History
Account
the HomeStack is a a stack navigator of two screens:
HomeScreen
TestScreen

I would like to hide the header of the stack navigator in both screens , which is done
and i would like to hide the header of the bottom tab navigator only in TestScreen

here's my code
BottomTabBar component

```
<Tab.navigator
   screenOptions={{headerShown: true}
  <Tab.screen name='home' component={HomeStack}/>
  <Tab.screen name='history' component={HistoryScreen}/>
  <Tab.screen name='account' component={AccountScreen}/>
</Tab.navigator>
```

the stack navigator:

```
<Stack.navigator
    screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
  <Stack.screen name='home' component={HomeScreen}/>
  <Stack.screen name='history' component={TestScreen}/>
</Stack.navigator>
```

The problem is that the header of the bottom navigator is shown in both HomeScreen and TestScreen
how an i achieve this behavior ?